# How to Allocate a Private IP address and Port with Ghostdriver

Tags: ip, ubuntu-14.04, ghostdriver

I wrote a **Ghostdriver** Maven Java project where I call many instances of the jar file using a shell script in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Each line in my shell script calls a new instance of my jar file.

**The format of each line:**

*screen -dmS name java -jar /path/name.jar arg1 arg2 arg3*

Currently I have 1 network interface (eth0) split up into multiple network aliases (eth0:1, eth0:2, etc), each alias points to a private IP which in turns points to a public IP.

I am trying to find the best way to allocate a private IP and possibly port number to each instance of my java program. Currently I call Ghostdriver inside my program.

**The way I call ghost driver within my program:**

```
public class className {

    PhantomJSDriver driver;
    public static final File PHANTOMJS_EXE = new     File("//home/username/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs");


    public className() {
        callGhostdriver();
        driver.quit();
    }

 private void callGhostdriver() {
        {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            caps.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path",
                    PHANTOMJS_EXE.getAbsolutePath());

            driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            actions = new Actions(driver);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Update****

I tried changing the callGhostdriver method but had no success.

```
private void callGhostdriver() {
DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
dcaps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
        PHANTOMJS_EXE.getAbsolutePath());
String[] phantomJsArgs = {"--webdriver=172.16.190.131:6781"};
dcaps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
        phantomJsArgs);
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcaps);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
actions = new Actions(driver);
}
```

> Argument --webdriver=IP:PORT seems to be overridden by a default
>   --webdriver call.

Output from running jar:

> *Apr 12, 2015 5:26:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService INFO: port: 8651
>   Apr 12, 2015 5:26:25 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService INFO: arguments:
>   [--webdriver=172.16.190.131:6781, --webdriver=8651,
>   --webdriver-logfile=/home/RemovedPath/phantomjsdriver.log] Apr 12, 2015 5:26:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService
>   INFO: environment: {} [INFO - 2015-04-12T21:26:26.584Z] GhostDriver -
>   Main - running on port 8651

Port 6781 with the different private IP should be what it is using but it uses 8651 instead.

Comment: I can set every capability but --webdriver=port, seems like you cannot change it, or it's a bug?

Comment: Can I at least change the port that it uses? This way I can use iptables to manage traffic. Currently it just picks a port at random.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a hackish way to set the port but still haven't figured out how to set the private ip, I may have to use iptables to route the traffic.

```
private void loadLightWeightDriverCustom() {
    ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, PHANTOMJS_EXE.getAbsolutePath());
    cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=false");
    cliArgsCap.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
    cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
    capabilities.setCapability(
            PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(Configure(cliArgsCap), capabilities);
}

private PhantomJSDriverService Configure(ArrayList<String> cap) {
    return new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder().usingPhantomJSExecutable(PHANTOMJS_EXE)
            .usingPort(5555)
            .usingCommandLineArguments(
                    (cap.toArray(new String[cap.size()])))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: HALP, there gotta be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -->
`List<String> cliArgsCap = Arrays.asList(
                "--webdriver=172.16.190.131:6781");
dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, it gave me the same output that I previously posted "INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=172.16.190.131:6781, --webdriver=3205, --webdriver-logfile=/home/RemovedPath/phantomjsdriver.log] Apr 12, 2015 5:26:25 PM "
[INFO  - 2015-04-13T22:05:13.944Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 3205

so it seems like its overriding what I put in for webdriver with another webdriver argument.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fix to the --webdriver command, https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/pull/438, I compiled that jar and loaded it in. Now I am getting

```
Apr 24, 2015 10:35:04 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService 
INFO: executable: C:*Removed Path\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe
Apr 24, 2015 10:35:04 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService 
INFO: port: 41533
Apr 24, 2015 10:35:04 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService 
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=127.0.0.1:6666, --webdriver-logfile=C:\Removed Path*\phantomjsdriver.log]
Apr 24, 2015 10:35:04 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService 
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO - 2015-04-24T14:35:06.222Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 6666
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'MBC5708', ip: '167.74.185.13', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
```

My method invoking phantomjs is:

```
  ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
    cliArgsCap.add("--webdriver=6666");
    capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,PHANTOMJS_EXE.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```